# How to have data flow between completely separately rendered React components?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I've been struggling with this for some time...
I have a node, express app, and render different components based on the link...
Example of what i'm talking about...

```
  var JSX_to_load = 'Messaging';
  res.render('generic-boilerplate-ejs-to-render-react-components', { 
    JSX_to_load : JSX_to_load, 
  })
```

The problem is that on one of the components I do your typical fetch to my back end....
But instead of comming back with a response on the front end, I want to "stay" on the backend and render a different component....
Does any one know how to do this?
The broader issue is: How to render component B from your backend with using data sent from component A?
best practices?
ps: this is my fetch that comes back

```
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.ROOT}/messaging`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderId: orderId,
      })
    })

    console.log(response)
```

Comment: Can you explain how component A is getting the data and how you want to render both of these components?

Comment: component A sends the data with a POST, but instead of re-rendering component A (default behaviour of POST fetch), I want to "stay" on the back end to render react component B. I think Server Side react can do this?

Comment: So are you only using SSR without CSR?